# Hide VAT for specific user roles in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, user-roles, tax

In WooCommerce I have some custom code to hide VAT for specific user roles, and it is working perfectly for all roles except for one called **Platinum**, where it doesn't hide the VAT but remains as all default user roles.

**What I need is for this code to hide VAT for platinum also - it does for the other roles I listed**

How can I make it work for my "platinum" user role too?

This is the code I use:

```
/**
 * Function that will check for user role and turn off VAT/tax for that role
 */
function wc_diff_rate_for_user() {

    // check for the user role
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can( 'bronze', 'sølv', 'guld', 'platinum' ) ) {

        // set the customer object to have no VAT
        WC()->customer->is_vat_exempt = true;
    }

}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wc_diff_rate_for_user', 1 );

/**
 * Function that filters the variable product hash based on user
 */
function wc_get_variation_prices_hash_filter( $hash, $item, $display ) {

    // check for the user role
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can( 'bronze', 'sølv', 'guld', 'platinum' ) ) {

        // clear key 2, which is where taxes are
        $hash['2'] = array();
    }

    // return the hash
    return $hash;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_variation_prices_hash', 'wc_get_variation_prices_hash_filter', 1, 3 );

/**
 * Function that removes the price suffix (inc. Tax) from variable products based on role
 */
function wc_get_price_suffix_filter( $price_display_suffix, $item ) {

    // check for the user role
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can( 'bronze', 'sølv', 'guld', 'platinum' ) ) {

        // return blank if it matches
        return '';
    }

    // return if unmatched
    return $price_display_suffix;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_suffix', 'wc_get_price_suffix_filter', 10, 2 );

//B2B Roller
add_role('bronze', __(
 'Bronze'),
 array(
 'read' => false, // Allows a user to read
 'create_posts' => false, // Allows user to create new posts
 'edit_posts' => false, // Allows user to edit their own posts
 )
);

add_role('sølv', __(
 'Sølv'),
 array(
 'read' => false, // Allows a user to read
 'create_posts' => false, // Allows user to create new posts
 'edit_posts' => false, // Allows user to edit their own posts
 )
);

add_role('guld', __(
 'Guld'),
 array(
 'read' => false, // Allows a user to read
 'create_posts' => false, // Allows user to create new posts
 'edit_posts' => false, // Allows user to edit their own posts
 )
);

add_role('platinum', __(
 'Platinum'),
 array(
 'read' => false, // Allows a user to read
 'create_posts' => false, // Allows user to create new posts
 'edit_posts' => false, // Allows user to edit their own posts
 )
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update 2**

**1) Your conditional function**

> First **[`current_user_can()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) is not recommended to be used with user roles directly** and can only have one capability (or in your case one user role) at the time…

Also in WooCommerce 3+ you will have to use **`WC()->customer->set_is_vat_exempt( true );`**
instead of `WC()->customer->is_vat_exempt = true;`

You are using a repetitive conditional function based on your special user roles 3 times. So I have set a custom conditional function that should work perfectly:

```
## The (repetitive) conditional function based on your "special" user roles 
function is_special_user_role(){
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) return false;

    $user = wp_get_current_user(); // current user
    $user_roles = $user->roles; // It's always an array (as a user can have many roles)

    // HERE your defined user roles
    $defined_user_roles = array( 'bronze', 'sølv', 'guld', 'platinum' );

    if ( count( array_intersect( $user_roles, $defined_user_roles ) ) > 0 ) return true;
    else return false; // ==> Added update here
}
```

And *(your others functions)*:

```
## Function that will check for user role and turn off VAT/tax for that role
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wc_diff_rate_for_user', 1 );
function wc_diff_rate_for_user() {
    // check for the user role and set the customer object to have no VAT
    if ( is_special_user_role() )
        WC()->customer->set_is_vat_exempt( true ); // Updated HERE
}

## Function that filters the variable product hash based on user
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_variation_prices_hash', 'wc_get_variation_prices_hash_filter', 1, 3 );
function wc_get_variation_prices_hash_filter( $hash, $item, $display ) {
    // check for the user role and clear key 2, which is where taxes are
    if ( is_special_user_role() )
        $hash['2'] = array();

    return $hash; // return the hash
}

## Function that removes the price suffix (inc. Tax) from variable products based on role
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_suffix', 'wc_get_price_suffix_filter', 10, 2 );
function wc_get_price_suffix_filter( $price_display_suffix, $item ) {
    // check for the user role return blank if it matches
    if ( is_special_user_role() )
        $price_display_suffix = '';

    return $price_display_suffix;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme or in any plugin file).*

All code is tested and works.

---

**2) For your user roles creation**

> Instead you could use the excellent and very complete [User Role Editor (free) plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/), that will allow you to create user roles, fine tune and check their capabilities *(for each created role)*.

For your user roles creation code, you should run it only once. I have revisited it, making some changes and compacted it.

```
## Special user roles creation ==> this should be runned just once!
function special_ser_role_creation(){
    // Your "Special" user roles slug / name pairs
    $special_roles_array = array(
        'bronze'   => __( 'Bronze' ),
        'sølv'     => __( 'Sølv' ),
        'guld'     => __( 'Guld' ),
        'platinum' => __( 'Platinum' ),
    );
    $roles_caps = array(
        'read'          => false, // Allows a user to read
        'create_posts'  => false, // Allows user to create new posts
        'edit_posts'    => false, // Allows user to edit their own posts
    );

    $existing_user_roles = array_keys( wp_roles()->get_names() );

    // Iterating through each user roles and create them
    foreach( $special_roles_array as $role_slug => $role_name ){
        // If user role doesn't exist yet we create it
        if (! in_array( $role_slug, $existing_user_roles) )
            add_role( $role_slug, $role_name, $roles_caps );
    }
}
// Run the function once (then comment it or remove it)
special_ser_role_creation();
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme or in any plugin file).*

Comment: It comes up with an error once I replaced it with my current code. I have attached the error in the top of the post, as it was too long to post here.

Comment: @eMikkelsen I have updated the conditional function (at the end). Try it it please. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the code is working because the function current_user_can takes in one parameter:
[current_user_can function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/)

I would rewrite all sections with this code:

```
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can( 'bronze', 'sølv', 'guld', 'platinum' ) ) {
```

To something like this:

```
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && ( current_user_can( 'bronze' ) || current_user_can( 'sølv' ) || current_user_can( 'guld' ) || current_user_can( 'platinum' ) ) ) {
```